# Python пишет цифры вместо изменения файла(или его создания с этими изменениями)

Tags: python

```
import csv
with open("keks.csv","w") as f:
w=csv.writer(f,delimiter=",") 
w.writerow(["odin","dva","tri"])
w.writerow(["chetiri","piat","shest"])
```

Такого файла,как "keks.csv" нет,я ожидаю его создания на рабочем столе с командой ,которую написал для текста внутри файла,но выдает такое значение,вместо создания нужного:

```
14
20
```

Comment: Почему именно на рабочем столе? Текущей рабочей папкой точно является именно рабочий стол?

Comment: C:\Users\dmitr\Desktop

Comment: Даже при условии,что файл создается ,что означают цифры после окончания кода

Comment: Метод writerow возвращает число записанных байт

Comment: Ох,извиняюсь за неопытность,спасибо за помощь!